# Deleting my Gmail profile picture doesn't remove it from conversations in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-plus

Basically, see the title. I do not have a Google+ account, just that screen that begs you to make one. Whenever I send an email on Gmail, it normally has my YouTube account profile picture.

I went into Gmail settings and removed the profile picture. However, the picture still shows when I log out and back in again in all email conversations.

I clicked on the 'Google+' link a the top of the Google page and tried to remove the image there. Of course, Google is being shady and doesn't let you do that!

Is there any way to remove the profile picture completely, totally, 100%?

I do not have a Google+ account and I do not want to make one.

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail settings select `No picture`.

It's worth to say that:

1. Those users that had added your email address to their contact management tools could store the old or any other picture in the contact record corresponding to your email address.
2. If you have a Google+ profile, Gmail contact manager will take the contact picture from there.
3. There are add-ons for Gmail that looks for pictures in public profiles and other social networks apps like Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter among others.

**References**
[Selecting your Gmail picture - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. I logged in to my Gmail account on a desktop computer, not from my phone or tablet. Once logged in, I clicked the "gear" icon near the top right of the screen, then "settings". Scrolling down, you will see "my picture" and an option to "select a picture". Once you click "select a picture", you will have an option to select "no picture".

Comment: I have tried this so many times today and it did not work. I also went through my G+ account and there it keeps telling me that I do not have a profil photo but when people get gmails from me or I see emails to me this photo of me which I did not consciously upload in the first place is still there. I do not even know how it got into gmail.. I also tried the same on the left side of the main page through OPTIONS next to the profile picture and then CHANGE PICTURE, then SELECT NO PICTURE, APPLY CHANGES. But the picture is still there.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple solution would be to change your picture to the default picture. Then while you technically DO have a picture it will appear that you don't.

[image: Googles Default Picture]